# Numpy Output Datatype Behavior of np.log1p(x)

Tags: python, numpy

Could somebody explain why I get different datatypes in each of those scenarios?

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ones((4,4), dtype=np.int)
>>> np.log1p(a).dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> a = np.ones((4,4), dtype=np.uint16)
>>> np.log1p(a).dtype
dtype('float32')

>>> a = np.ones((4,4), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> np.log1p(a).dtype
dtype('float16')
```